# Lagrange Multiplier as Convex Combination

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Suppose I want to solve the constrained optimization problem
$$
\inf_{\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: g(x)=0\}} f(x),
$$
where $f$ is convex and $g$ is lsc.
I know I can rewrite it as a minimax problem
$$
\inf_{\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: g(x)=0\}} \sup_{\lambda \in [0,\infty)}f(x) + \lambda g(x).
$$

Can I rewrite this as
$$
\inf_{\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: g(x)=0\}} \sup_{\lambda \in (0,1])}
(1-\lambda) f(x) + \lambda g(x)?
$$
If not, under what conditions would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, since your $\inf$ still contains the constraint $g(x) = 0$. Is this intended?

Comment: You need $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of nonnegative. And your last operation changes the objective value, whereas the first does not.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are non-negative then this should not be an issue right?

Comment: Not an issue for $\lambda \geq 0$ because then $g(x)=0$ is equivalent to $g(x) \leq 0$. However, the other comments (including gerw's) are still valid.